# Vuex state not update without reload

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

```html
  <template>
    <ContactField
      v-for="(field, $fieldIndex) in contact.fields"
      :key="$fieldIndex"
      :fieldIndex="$fieldIndex"
      :contact="contact"
      :fieldName="field.fieldName"
      v-model="field.fieldValue"
    />
    <div>
      Add field
      <input type="text" v-model="newFieldName" />
      <input type="text" v-model="newFieldValue" />
      <button @click="addFieldToContact">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="saveChanges">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newFieldName: '',
      newFieldValue: '',
    }
  },
  components: {
    ContactField
  },
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$route.params.id
    },
    ...mapGetters(['getContact']),
    contact() {
      return this.getContact(this.id)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addFieldToContact() {
      this.$store.commit('ADD_FIELD', {
        contact: this.contact,
        fieldName: this.newFieldName,
        fieldValue: this.newFieldValue
      })
      this.newFieldName = ''
      this.newFieldValue = ''
    }
  }
}
```

Vuex store

```js
const contacts = ...
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    contacts
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_FIELD(state, { contact, fieldName, fieldValue }) {
      contact.fields.push({
        fieldName: fieldName,
        fieldValue: fieldValue
      })
    }
  },
getters: {
    getContact: state => id => {
      for (const contact of state.contacts) {
        if (contact.id == id) {
          return contact
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

When i click button "add" i can see what fields created on page but not in state(state hasn't this field's that i add just now) but if i refresh page state add to yourself this fields.
Question: is this correct? Or it depends on the situation? Do I need to update state directly?
Some code i delete because i cant ask when i use a lot of code.

Comment: Your `state` config doesn't look right (what is `contacts`?) and you never change anything on `state` in your mutation

Comment: Where is your `getContact` getter?

Comment: I change contacts that refers to the state

Comment: `const contacts = ...` doesn't really tell me anything. Please provide some details

Comment: ```
[
  {
    id: 'ssfg',
    fields: [
      {
        fieldName: 'ФИО',
        fieldValue: 'Иванов Иван'
      },
      {
        fieldName: 'Номер телефона',
        fieldValue: '+79523695475'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```
I use plugin to save changes to state, but default state you can see above

Answer (score 1):

Your `contacts` are not changed trough the state. You are pushing your new `object` to the variable passed to the `ADD_FIELD` method.

Maybe you can try to find and replace the `contact` in your `contacts` array. Or if it is new one just push it to `contacts`. This should happen at the end of your `ADD_FIELD(...)` method.

Comment: This is the question of how best to do it. I change state what referenced to this object, but is it best practice?

Comment: Working with `vuex` is always best-practice. I would move the initialisation of the `contacts` inside of the state and update the array every time something happens. Like that I will make sure that i can also change the whole array as well as editing parts from it. Moreover, the getter you have will always take the most recent records because you have changed it trough your state. (my personal preferences, that is how i am handling this CRUD operations)